# how to change form field in method is_valid()

Tags: django

I have two models

```
class Friend(models.Model):
       me = models.ForeignKey(User)
       friend = models.ForeignKey(User)
       remark = models.CharField(max_length=15)

      def __unicode__(self):
            return self.remark

class Message(models.Model):
       from_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
       to_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
       ...
```

I make a form for Message

```
class MessageForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
              model = Message
```

but when i display the form in html, i hope i display to_user's choice list just by 'remark' ( in Friend model)

and I override MessageForm 's **init** method like follow:

```
class MessageForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
              model = Message
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
              super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
              init = kwargs.get('initial')
              if init:
                  if 'from_user' in init:
                       me = init['from_user']
                       self.fields['to_user'].queryset = Friend.objects.filter(me=me)
```

well when  the data post, the form.is_valid() raise error :  Cannot assign "": "Message.to_user" must be a "User" instance.

so i want to change self.fields['to_user'] 's value  before is_valid() is call like:

```
def is_valid(self):
     # do something  to fix the problem
     super(MessageForm, self).is_valid()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_valid()` calls the `clean()` method of the form, so put your hack in there:

```
def clean(self):
    # hack hack hack, operating on self.cleaned_data

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: There are cleaner/arguably better ways to do it than the approach you want to take, but this'll work.

Comment: [self._clean_fields()](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L270) will be call first than [self.clean()](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L297) which is the form-wide method and except will raise at self._clean_fields() [self.clean(value)](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L287)

Comment: @SteveJalim you said there is cleaner and better ways. Could you elaborate on these ways?

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote that but ruandao's tip is probably what I was thinking, or even more specifically adding a clean_mycustomfield() method to target your cleanup as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

You need [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) in your form, which will take care of the relationship look up.